# Monit fails to start process

Tags: bash, monit

I've written a scrip that works fine to start and stop a server.

```
#!/bin/bash

PID_FILE='/var/run/rserve.pid'

start() {
       touch $PID_FILE
       eval "/usr/bin/R CMD Rserve"
       PID=$(ps aux | grep Rserve | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
       echo "Starting Rserve with PID $PID"
       echo $PID > $PID_FILE
}
stop () {
       pkill Rserve
       rm $PID_FILE
       echo "Stopping Rserve"
}

case $1 in
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)  
       stop
       ;;
     *)  
       echo "usage: rserve {start|stop}" ;;
 esac
 exit 0
```

If I start it by running

```
rserve start
```

and then start `monit` it will correctly capture the PID and the server:

```
The Monit daemon 5.3.2 uptime: 0m 

Remote Host 'localhost'
  status                            Online with all services
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  port response time                0.000s to localhost:6311 [DEFAULT via TCP]
  data collected                    Mon, 13 May 2013 20:03:50

System 'system_gauss'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  load average                      [0.37] [0.29] [0.25]
  cpu                               0.0%us 0.2%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                      524044 kB [25.6%]
  swap usage                        4848 kB [0.1%]
  data collected                    Mon, 13 May 2013 20:03:50
```

If I stop it, it will properly kill the process and unmonitor it. However if I start it again, it won't start the server again:

```
ps ax | grep Rserve | grep -vc grep
1
monit stop localhost
ps ax | grep Rserve | grep -vc grep
0
monit start localhost

[UTC May 13 20:07:24] info     : 'localhost' start on user request
[UTC May 13 20:07:24] info     : monit daemon at 4370 awakened
[UTC May 13 20:07:24] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[UTC May 13 20:07:24] info     : 'localhost' start: /usr/bin/rserve
[UTC May 13 20:07:24] info     : 'localhost' start action done
[UTC May 13 20:07:34] error    : 'localhost' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:6311] via TCP
```

Here is the monitrc:

```
check host localhost with address 127.0.0.1
  start = "/usr/bin/rserve start"
  stop = "/usr/bin/rserve stop"
  if failed host localhost port 6311 type tcp with timeout 15 seconds for 5 cycles
    then restart
```

Comment: Could it be your program needs more then 10 seconds to start up?

Comment: I also tried timeout 30, and it takes less than 5 seconds to start up. Even if I put the original command "R CMD Rserve" with the "\bin\bash -c" on the monitrc, it won't work. It seems it can't start it from monit daemon.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having similar problems.

Comment: Im having the same issues. Cannot figure out why it won't start

Answer (score 8):

I had problem start or stop process via shell too.
One solution might be add "/bin/bash" in the config like this:

```
start program = "/bin/bash /urs/bin/rserv start"
stop program = "/bin/bash /urs/bin/rserv stop"
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Btw, I got the info from this http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2008-12/msg00004.html

Comment: Also see this http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2010-01/msg00035.html

Comment: This solution is described in the FAQs of monit in more Detail to why it is necessary and how to use it http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ#execution

Answer (score 4):

monit is a silent killer. It does not tell you anything. Here are things I would check which monit won't help you identify

1. Check permissions of all the files you are reading / writing. If you are redirecting output to a file, make sure that file is writable by uid and gid you are using to execute the program
2. Again check exec permission on the program you are trying to run
3. Specify full path to any program you are trying to execute ( not strictly necessary, but you don't have to worry about path not being set if you always specify full path )
4. Make sure you can run the program outside of monit without any error before trying to investigate why monit is not starting.

Answer (score 1):

If the Monit log is displaying

```
failed to start (exit status -1) -- no output
```

Then it may be that you're trying to run a script without any of the Bash infrastructure. You can run such a command by wrapping it in `/bin/bash -c`, like so:

```
check process my-process
  matching "my-process-name"
  start program = "/bin/bash -c '/etc/init.d/my-init-script'"
```

Answer (score 0):

When monit starts it checks for its own pidfile and checks if the process with 
matching PID is running already - if it does, then it just wakes up this 
process.

in your case, check if this pid is being used by some other process:
ps -ef |grep 4370

if yes, then you need to remove the below file(usually under /run directory) and start monit again:
monit.pid

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that the stop command was not being run, even though I specifically specified "then restart" on the configuration.
The solution was just to change:
start program = "/etc/init.d/.... restart"